# How to load a font file from css file into Angular project

Tags: css, angular, angular7, angular8

I have this project with fonts, images and CSS files under the folder assets:

[image]

How I can import the fonts into this CSS file?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: lg;
    src: url(./assets/fonts/lgd641.eot?n1z373);
    src: url(./assets/fonts/lgd41d.eot?#iefixn1z373) format("embedded-opentype"), url(./assets/fonts/lgd641.woff?n1z373) format("woff"), url(./assets/fonts/lgd641.ttf?n1z373) format("truetype"), url(./assets/fonts/lgd641.svg?n1z373#lg) format("svg");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Now I get not found.

[image]

Comment: Can you try `url('assets/fonts/lgd641.eot?n1z373')`?

Comment: Well, it's working.

Comment: Are you saying it's working with a path like 'assets/fonts/whatever`? Or was it a different change/pattern that allowed it to work?

Comment: yes with 'assets/fonts/whatever` it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the paths to the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: lg;
    src: url(assets/fonts/lgd641.eot?n1z373);
    src: url(assets/fonts/lgd41d.eot?#iefixn1z373) format("embedded-opentype"), url(assets/fonts/lgd641.woff?n1z373) format("woff"), url(assets/fonts/lgd641.ttf?n1z373) format("truetype"), url(assets/fonts/lgd641.svg?n1z373#lg) format("svg");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Do you know the solution for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58512137/include-links-into-html-head-into-angular-project

Answer (score 0):

you can use ../fonts/file-name path to the font directory in place of ./assets/fonts in css file.